# Google maps getmap()> getMapAsycn() error in Android new update

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Can anyone help me with this code. It says i need to change the `getMap()` to `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback);` and need to create new method `OnMapReady`. I follow step by step from the tutorial on youtube. I need to implement this on my project. If anyone could help me I will be so thankful. Although I am new to android app dev.

MapActivity.java

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMapAsync(this);

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

Below is the full code of MapActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {



public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

/*
 * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
 * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
 */
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMapAsync(this);

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }else{
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up your map when the `onMapReady` function is called:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. And I've added few function and it is work :) again thank you

Comment: Glad to help :) if this solution solved your problem, consider marking it as the accepted answer/upvoting it